# InternalError during model.fit() while running on Colab TPU

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, bert-language-model, tpu

I am attempting to fine-tune an expertBERT model from TensorFlow Hub on the Sentiment140 TFDS in Google Colab. However, I encounter the following error:

`InternalError: RET_CHECK failure (third_party/tensorflow/core/tpu/graph_rewrite/distributed_tpu_rewrite_pass.cc:1992) arg_shape.handle_type != DT_INVALID  input edge: [id=3880 model_4_keras_layer_11_262798:0 -> cluster_train_function:652]`

The code works fine when run on CPU, but I have not been able to find a solution to this error, despite having seen a similar question on Stack Overflow.

```
def create_model():
    bert_model = hub.KerasLayer(BERT_URL, trainable=True)
    preprocessor_model = hub.KerasLayer(PREPROCESSOR_URL)

    input_text = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name="input_layer")
    bert_inputs = preprocessor_model(input_text)
    bert_outputs = bert_model(bert_inputs)
    drop = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(bert_outputs.get("pooled_output"))
    output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", name="output_layer")(drop)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_text, outputs=output_layer)
    return model


def optimize_ds(dataset, batch_size):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dataset["train"]).take(60000) #JUST A TINY SAMPLE
    dataset_size = dataset.cardinality().numpy()
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    return dataset, dataset_size

with strategy.scope():
    metrics = tf.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()
    loss_function = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)

    train_dataset, train_data_size = optimize_ds(in_memory_ds, BATCH_SIZE)
    print(train_data_size)
    steps_per_epoch = train_data_size    
    num_train_steps = steps_per_epoch * EPOCHS
    num_warmup_steps = num_train_steps
    model = create_model()
    print(train_dataset.take(1))

    optimizer = optimization.create_optimizer(
        init_lr=INIT_LR,
        num_train_steps=num_train_steps,
        num_warmup_steps=num_warmup_steps,
        optimizer_type="adamw"
    )

    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss_function, metrics=[metrics])

    early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=PATIENCE, restore_best_weights=True)

    checkpoint_path = "/content/cp.ckpt"
    checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)
    options = tf.train.CheckpointOptions(experimental_io_device="/job:localhost")
    cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                        save_weights_only=True,
                                                        save_best_only=True,
                                                        verbose=1, options=options)
    latest_checkpoint = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir)
    if latest_checkpoint is not None:
        print(latest_checkpoint)
        model.load_weights(latest_checkpoint)

    history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                        callbacks=[early_stop, cp_callback])
```

That's a portion of my entire code. I have included all the necessary boilerplate code to execute the code on TPUs

Comment: Could you share a full reproducible Colab/code?

Could you test without `callbacks=[early_stop, cp_callback]`?

Answer (score 0):

This issue [InternalError when using TPU for training Keras model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70479279/internalerror-when-using-tpu-for-training-keras-model)
suggests that there might be a problem with num steps you define. Is your batch_size=1? If not, then you probably have error with steps_per_epoch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to preprocess the inputs outside the model rather than inside the model. TPU's are incapable of carrying out operations with strings.
Preprocessor Url should be inside the optimize_ds

```py
def bert_preprocessing_model(seq_length=512):
    input_segments = [keras.layers.Input(shape=(),dtype=tf.string)]
    bert_preprocess = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3")
    tokenize = hub.KerasLayer(bert_preprocess.tokenize,name="tokenizer")
    out_sequence = [tokenize(input_segments)]
    packer = hub.KerasLayer(bert_preprocess.bert_pack_inputs,arguments=dict(seq_length=seq_length),name="packer")
    model_inputs = packer(out_sequence)
    return keras.Model(input_segments,model_inputs)
```

Then use it in your optimize_ds

```py
bert_preprocessor = bert_preprocessing_model()#Returns a model
def optimize_ds(dataset, batch_size,bert_preprocessor):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dataset["train"]).take(60000) #JUST A TINY SAMPLE
    dataset_size = dataset.cardinality().numpy()
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda single_example: (bert_preprocessor(single_example['text']),single_example['label']))
    dataset.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    return dataset, dataset_size
```

Basically the preprocessors of all tfhub bert models are like in a sense

```py
keras.layers.TextVectorization()
```

layers. but trained on large corpus and optimized for bert embeddings. and the output it gives when you pass a string into it is a dictionary of input_word_ids,input_type_ids,input_mask which only have tf.int32 numbers with shape (1,seq_length) so whatever inputs you are passing to tpu becomes tf.int32 rather than strings

This is the [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/text/blob/master/docs/tutorials/bert_glue.ipynb#scrollTo=_XgTpm9ZxoN9) I followed

This is my [notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/sohailmd123/sentimentmodelling-with-bertembeddings-on-tpu-s) for imdb reviews where i used small bert embeddings

This is my [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ii0D2GokcdgxZVjB7oHKy0Lt-I8Ykuin#scrollTo=O7CnNqokk-n6) on using just normal keras in-built embeddings and textvectorization layers.See that i used the text vectorization on inputs before passing it to inputs so now the inputs are just tf.int32 just the way tpu accepts